# Is this bad ju-ju? (getting a Button to hang out with RadioButtons in a RadioGroup)?

Tags: android-layout

```
<TableRow >

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroupContacts"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioAllContacts"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="To Anybody in my Contact List" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioSelectedContacts"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Only to Selected People in my Contact List" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonOpenContactList"
            android:text="Open Contact List" />
    </RadioGroup>
</TableRow>
```

This displays just fine, but it doesn't seem right - shouldn't everything in a RadioGroup be a RadioButton?

If I move the Button outside the RadioGroup but still within the TableRow, it works fine, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, everything in a `RadioGroup` should be a `RadioButton`; that's the whole purpose of a `RadioGroup` - to group `RadioButtons`.

Comment: So why does it ALLOW other widgets to crash the party? Is this a nod to the C crowd (anything is allowed, if you don't know what you're doing, tough!)?

Comment: @Clay, why does Windows allow you to format your `C:` drive? Why do dogs hate cats (and vice versa), but some cats get along with dogs? I can't answer that, but I guess common sense has to take over sometimes - a `RadioGroup` should group thing that are part of `Radio`, and `RadioButtons` seem to be the only members. Kinda like a `Girl Scout group` shouldn't have boys in it? :)

Comment: OK, got it; however, some commen scents are not pleasant.